# How to disable rails lazy loading for a directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a set of classes that depend on them being required() in a specific order because I'm using the class method #inherited on the parent.

Since rails only attempts to load classes when they are first used, the #inherited method of the parent class is only loaded sometimes and not always.

Is it possible to eager load this classes in a rails way? or should I just place them in another directory and call 'require'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `config.eager_load_paths` attribute that you can set in your environments/(development|production).rb file.

> config.eager_load_paths accepts an
>   array of paths from which Rails will
>   eager load on boot if cache classes is
>   enabled. Defaults to every folder in
>   the app directory of the application.
>   All elements of this array must also
>   be in load_paths.

from [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

Comment: This seems to work, but adds another problem. My file is called "provider_foo.rb" and defines a class called "ProviderFoo" that inherits from "Provider". Now rails complains that it expected provider_foo.rb to define ProviderFoo. It does, but inherited from Provider. If I remove the inheritance, the error disappears but my code doesn't work.